# Is this a valid query? (Repetition of Aliases)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, alias

I am trying to create nested join statements and use alias for programming purposes. Let me give you a list of tables I'm trying to join and their foreign keys.

```
TABLE1: id (Foreign key)
TABLE2: id (primary key), idx (foreign key)
TABLE3: id (primary key), idx (primary key)
TABLE4: id (primary key), idx (primary key)`

SELECT * 
FROM (((TABLE1 JOIN
        TABLE2
        ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
       ) AS NEW_TABLE JOIN
       TABLE3
       ON NEW_TABLE.id = TABLE3.id AND NEW_TABLE.idx = TABLE3.idx
      ) AS NEW_TABLE JOIN
      TABLE4
      ON NEW_TABLE.id = TABLE4.id AND
         NEW_TABLE.idx = TABLE4.idx
     );
```

Can you let me know if this is a valid query and using aliases this way works?

Comment: Do you have a particular DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need to nest complete queries:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id ) A 
    JOIN TABLE3 ON A.id = TABLE3.id AND A.idx = TABLE3.idx) B 
  JOIN TABLE4 ON B.id = TABLE4.id AND B.idx = TABLE4.idx;
```

although, without knowing the contents of the tables it's hard to say what kind of results you might get or whether your query is even valid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 JOIN
     TABLE2
     ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id JOIN
     TABLE3
     ON TABLE1.id = TABLE3.id AND TABLE2.idx = TABLE3.idx
     TABLE4
     ON TABLE1.id = TABLE4.id AND
        TABLE2.idx = TABLE4.idx;
```

(Well, actually, I would use table aliases but this is the idea.)

The parentheses do not do anything for you.  I also think re-using the `NEW_TABLE` alias is likely to generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Format like below..

```
SELECT * FROM 
  TABLE1 
     JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
     JOIN TABLE3 ON Table1.id = TABLE3.id 
        AND Table2.idx = TABLE3.idx
   JOIN TABLE4 ON Table3.id = TABLE4.id 
      AND Table3.idx = TABLE4.idx
```